# Limiting MySQL results to the first of many groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a query like

```
("SELECT size FROM block WHERE block_model = '".$_SESSION['block']."'")
```

This gives me a series of results like

> big big big medium medium medium small small small

Is there some way that I can LIMIT each 'set' to only its first result, so that I only end up with 1 big, 1 medium, 1 small other than editing my database structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) keyword in MySQL.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT size
 FROM block
 WHERE block_model = '" . $_SESSION['block'] . "'"
```

Depending on your MySQL version and how your table is setup, you can also use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause for potentially better performance.

```
 "SELECT size
  FROM block
  WHERE block_model = '" . $_SESSION['block'] . "'
  GROUP BY size"
```

Comment: Thanks for that added bit of information about GROUP BY, very handy.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `DISTINCT` which gets only unique records

```
$sessionVal = $_SESSION['block'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM block WHERE block_model = '$sessionVal'";
```

Comment: Oh that's amazing, I never knew about DISTINCT. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome `:D` you might want to use `PDO` or `MySQLi` also

Comment: Yep, already using PDO. Learned that the hard way when Stackoverflow yelled at me for still using mysql_* functions haha!